# "Thanks, my lovelies!"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, idioms

I was looking for a phrase to thank multiple people. It's supposed to be an endearment for friends but not super close friends. Is this an appropriate reply to compliments or birthday wishes, e.g. on facebook? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: There are so many possibilities that this is impossible to answer within this format.

Comment: Only if you know them well and aren't afraid of coming off as sarcastic, foppish, or condescending.

Comment: thank you! what is "foppish"?

Comment: but is it a commenly used idiomatic expression? I'v seen it a lot on Instagram or Facebook, e.g. "Thanks my lovelies for the likes of recent piccies :)) x"

Comment: This is what we use at the auto repair shop where I work.

Comment: @mitch in what context do you use it?

Comment: One important tag is lacking:  stuational formulas, ie fixed expressioms in exactly specified situations. That is not the same as idioms.

Comment: @ada I was being silly. 'lovelies' sounds very cutesy and would probably make a bunch of men at an auto repair shop feel uncomfortable. So it would be funny if they used it among themselves.

Comment: @bib: you're not gonna praise anyone, are you?

Comment: @oerkelens Well, I didn't come to bury them.

Comment: OP's inability or unwillingness to look up "foppish" nicely sums um everything that's wrong with this question.

Answer (score 2):

If all the people are social contemporaries, you can say what you wish. If your relationship to some of the people is subordinate in some way, the best phrase would be, ***"Thanks to all.."*** (for the lovely whatever)

Answer (score 1):

In American English, "my lovelies" usually appears in contexts where an evil witch or sorceress queen of fairy tale is addressing her minions.  It would be very difficult to use the phrase here without irony.

Comment: I agree, "my lovelies" has a creepy connotation, at least in the U.S.

Comment: oh okay, really?! I'm not a native speaker, so I have never read any fairytales in English. Maybe there are multiple meanings? I've come across a lot of posts like "Merry Xmas, my lovelies" , "Goodnight, my lovelies" , " Thank you all my lovelies for the birthday wishes...". These certainly didn't refer to minions of sorts ;)

Comment: Well, it does have the literal meaning "my lovely ones".  It expresses the speaker's fondness for the lovely ones:  a cohort of friends, flowers in a pot the speaker has lovingly tended, a team of prize mares pulling a carriage, whatever. But in American popular culture, it has been "tainted" by a TV and film trope: the dastardly villain refers to the damsel he has made his prisoner as "my pretty".  The flowers are more likely to be fly-traps than baby's-breath when the gardener calls them "my lovelies" :)

Answer (score -1):

As with most questions of colloquial language, the answer is highly subjective.

I've heard Americans and Finns (speaking/writing in English) use "thanks, my lovelies!" (and "bye, my lovelies" etc.), but I've never heard Irish people use it, for example.

Personally, I think it's charming and warm, but it really depends on your audience, and if it's not in use where you are, it may come across as strange (though that may not bother you). If you're looking for a neutral turn of phrase, a simple "Thanks, everyone!" works.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for something warm, as the compliments were really sweet and cordial as well.

Comment: @ada From your comment above (I hadn't seen it when I answered), it sounds like it is in use in your social circle, and thus it isn't at all strange that you would use it too.